# How to display one item on top of other items by using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**By using **Flexbox**, I want to **center three elements inside a photo and then put one element on top of those three**:**

[image]

**I tried this to center them and obviously all the items get centered, whereas I only want the three boxes to be centered:**

```
display: inline-flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

**These are the HTML and CSS codes for that particular section:**

*HTML:*

```
        <section class="banner-3">
            <article>
                <h2 id="locations">Locations</h2>
                <div class="address">
                    <h3>Downtown</h3>
                    <p>384 West 4th St</p>
                    <p>Suite 108</p>
                    <p>Portland, Maine</p>
                </div>
                <div class="address">
                    <h3>East Bayside</h3>
                    <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
                    <p>(Northwest Corner)</p>
                    <p>Portland, Maine</p>
                </div>
                <div class="address">
                    <h3>Oakdale</h3>
                    <p>515 Crescent Avenue</p>
                    <p>Second Floor</p>
                    <p>Portland, Maine</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
```

*CSS:*

```
.banner-3 article {
    height: 500px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-image: url("../images/img-locations-background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.banner-3 .address {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 20px;
}

.address h3, p {
    margin: 25px auto;
}
```

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: You have to wait for it! I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap these three elements into a `container` with `display: flex; flex-direction: row`. This will make the container display horizontally its contents. Also give the `article` style as `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` This will make the `h2` align above thode 3 cards.

```css
.banner-3 article {
  height: 500px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  width: 1200px;
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/photographer.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner-3 .address {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.address h3,
p {
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner-3">
  <article>
    <h2 id="locations">Locations</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="address">
        <h3>Downtown</h3>
        <p>384 West 4th St</p>
        <p>Suite 108</p>
        <p>Portland, Maine</p>
      </div>
      <div class="address">
        <h3>East Bayside</h3>
        <p>3433 Phisherman's Avenue</p>
        <p>(Northwest Corner)</p>
        <p>Portland, Maine</p>
      </div>
      <div class="address">
        <h3>Oakdale</h3>
        <p>515 Crescent Avenue</p>
        <p>Second Floor</p>
        <p>Portland, Maine</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```